# How to link oracle instant client to navicat

Tags: database, macos, navicat, oracle8

I am trying to link oracle client instant with navicat premium. I have a MacBook Pro 15 inches (64 - bit).
I followed the instructions mentioned in these two links.

1) http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Instant_client_required

2) http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_can_I_connect_Oracle_8i_using_Navicat_Mac_version_11%3F

however when I try to connect to the server that I am trying to collect the data from. It gives me this error messages

dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 10): no suitable image found. Did find:/Library/instantclient_10_2/libclntsh.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

dlopen(libclntsh.dylib.11.1, 10): image not found

Can some please help me??? What should I do? Should I link it to the 32-bit version or the 64-bit one?? Also what should I do about the missing files and the mismatching one. What I know is that the mismatch one is build for the i386 not for x86_64, but I don't know where to find the X86_64 one.